# ¿Cómo puedo obtener valores duplicados de una lista separados en diferentes listas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy haciendo un programa con Windows Forms (C#) y necesito hacer algo como lo siguiente:
Digamos que tengo una Lista de objetos (instancias de una clase que yo hice llamada Producto), el objeto tiene dos propiedades: Nombre (string) y Precio (int).
Esta lista es propensa de tener objetos duplicados, es por eso que necesito obtenerlos.
Supongamos que así es como se ve la lista original (con duplicados e ignorando el precio):

```
Teléfono
Teléfono
Computadora
Laptop
Reproductor
Reproductor
```

Necesito obtener en este caso, dos listas que contengan los duplicados del nombre, por lo que terminaría con una lista A:

```
Teléfono
Teléfono
```

Y una segunda lista:

```
Reproductor
Reproductor
```

¿Cómo podría lograr esto? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te ayudas con `linq` seria bastante simple ya que solo deberias agrupar

Algo como esto

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> lista = new List<string>{"Teléfono","Teléfono","Computadora", "Laptop", "Reproductor", "Reproductor" };

        var query = lista.GroupBy(x=> x)
                        .Where(x=> x.Count() > 1)
                        .Select(x=> x)
                        .ToList();

        var lista1 = query[0];
        var lista2 = query[1];

        foreach(var item1 in lista1){
            Console.WriteLine(item1);
        }
        foreach(var item2 in lista2){
            Console.WriteLine(item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Si quieres esa misma query pero usando la notacion linq podria ser

```
    var query = (from item in lista
                  group item by item into g
                where g.Count() > 1
                select g).ToList();
```